# add sweetalert2 confirm delete in php without json data

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3, sweetalert2

How to use sweetalert2 with delete function in button href ?
i have button like this

```
<button type="button" id="btnDelete" href=" <?php echo site_url('administrator/master/delete/' . $a->idDept); ?>" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash but" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"></button>

 $('.btnDelete').click(function() {
       swal.fire({
           title: 'Are you sure?',
           text: "It will permanently deleted !",
           type: 'warning',
           showCancelButton: true,
           confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
           cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
           confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
       }).then(function() {
           swal.fire(
               'Deleted!',
               'Your file has been deleted.',
               'success'
           );
       });
   });
```

sweetalert2 working but not delete the data

Comment: There's nothing in your code which would contact your server. Why is there a `href` attribute for a button, it doesn't do anything when attached to a button.

Comment: move your delete url to your click function,
use javascript to redirect href url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass the fetch/ajax method in Swal.fire call.

```
  $('.btnDelete').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  icon: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
  preConfirm: () => {
    return fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(response.statusText)
        }
        return response.json()
      })
      .catch(error => {
        Swal.showValidationMessage(
          `Request failed: ${error}`
        )
      })
  }
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    Swal.fire(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  }
});
});
```

Use this example codepan and modify it as you need.
https://codepen.io/ympervej/pen/wvJQyOr